# JAVAFX Call a function in a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, function, javafx

I'm currently trying to call a function from my `Thread` (which is a simple counter). The Thread is doing well without the function, but when I try to call it, I'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-5
at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:236)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.remove(VetoableListDecorator.java:329)
at window.GamePane.destroyCardPane(GamePane.java:716)
at window.GamePane.timeIsUp(GamePane.java:810)
at window.GamePane$1.run(GamePane.java:74)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So there is my Thread:

```
public Thread getCounter() {
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println(i);
                        if(i == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Time is up");
                            timeIsUp();
                            System.out.println("test");
                            break;
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        counter.setDaemon(true);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Number from 5 to 0 and "Time is up" appear, but then I get the error.

And this is the function i'm trying to call when the counter reach 0:

```
public void timeIsUp() {
    getCounter().interrupt(); // stopping the thread? I tried without this and it's still the same error
    if (turn+1 < nbPlayers) {
        turn++;
    }  else {
        turn = 0;
    }
    getBtnDes().setDisable(false); // Disable a button
    destroyCardPane(); // remove an AnchorPane from this.children()
}
```

If you guys need other stuff, class or function to help me out, just let me know in the comment and I'll add it as fast as I can.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

All UI operations **must** be performed on the FX Application Thread. You can call `Platform.runLater(...)` from a background thread and pass it a `Runnable` which will be executed on the FX Application Thread.

There is really no need here to interrupt the existing thread. If you reorder the code so that you sleep first, then check, then the thread will be about to exit anyway:

```
public Thread getCounter() {
    if(counter == null) {
        counter = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                        System.out.println(i);
                        if(i == 0) {
                            System.out.println("Time is up");

                            Platform.runLater(this::timeIsUp);

                            System.out.println("test");
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        counter.setDaemon(true);
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Now you can remove the interrupt call from the `timeIsUp()` method.

```
public void timeIsUp() {
    if (turn+1 < nbPlayers) {
        turn++;
    }  else {
        turn = 0;
    }
    getBtnDes().setDisable(false); // Disable a button
    destroyCardPane(); // remove an AnchorPane from this.children()
}
```

Note you can do all of this without threads at all, using a `Timeline`:

```
Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
for (int i = 5 ; i >= 0 ; i=--) {
    final int count = i ;
    KeyFrame frame = new KeyFrame(Duration.seconds(5-i), e -> System.out.println(count));
    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(frame);
}
timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {
    System.out.println("Time is up");
    timeIsUp();
});
timeline.play();
```

Here there is no blocking (so no need for threads), and the key frame's event handler and the `onFinished` handler are executed on the FX Application Thread, so it is safe to update the UI there.

Comment: @MA-Moustache I would definitely recommend using the `Timeline` instead

Answer (score 0):

Only the JavaFX thread can do operations on the JavaFX Scene graph. If you need to change something in JavaFX from another thread, you need to use `Platform.runLater(Runnable)`.